# Hook any php file into the wordpress api

Tags: hooks, api

Say I just have a dumb .php file sitting on my WP server and I wanted it to access WP info through the API, how would I go about doing that? For example if I wanted to call

```
 bloginfo('url');
```

As I have scored myself a downvote (with no explanation) I will expound upon why I am interested in this. Sure I can access WP API from all the built-in pages. But let's say I have a page that has little to do with WP. Seems like a lot of overhead to create say a custom template page and then hook it into an actual post, all so that I can have access to a few WP API calls.

I ended up using something like this:

```
require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/wp-blog-header.php';
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mean something like this?

```
<?php
require 'path/to/wordpress/wp-blog-header.php';
bloginfo('url');
?>
```

Comment: I've always used `wp-load.php` and `define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);`, I'm curious what the differences are, if any.

Comment: [The codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Integrating_WordPress_with_Your_Website) is using the `wp-blog-header.php` file. I've just looked at the two files and it seems that `wp-blog-header.php` also calls `wp-load.php`, `template-loader.php` and the function `wp()`. The `wp()` function then calls the main() method of the `WP` class which sets up all required global variables. The constant `WP_USE_THEMES` is by default false and only set in the index.php which is never called here, so it I think it isn't really necessary.

Comment: Thank-you for the how-to as well as some discussion on the why. I am always more interested in that part.